# How to change variable values in an array of variables in JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, variables

Not sure if this is possible to even do so I'll give it a quick shot and see if anyone has any solutions, ***ahem***.
Is there any way I could store these variables into an array, and change them through the array as such;

```
function themepreviewchange() {pretaskbartxt=curcolsch[0];pretaskbartxtprs=curcolsch[1];preactivetitle=curcolsch[2];preinactivetitle=curcolsch[3];pretbgradinactive1=curcolsch[4];
   pretbgradinactive2=curcolsch[5];pretbgradactive1=curcolsch[6];pretbgradactive2=curcolsch[7];cpwhite=curcolsch[8];cplightg=curcolsch[9];cpsilver=curcolsch[10];cpmidgray=curcolsch[11];
   cpgray=curcolsch[12];cpblack=curcolsch[13];cpblue=curcolsch[14];cpprussian=curcolsch[15];cpwincyan=curcolsch[16];cpyellow=curcolsch[17];cpfont=curcolsch[18];cphover=curcolsch[19];
   cpatext=curcolsch[20];preinvert=curcolsch[21];shuffleflop=curcolsch[22];discheckinv=curcolsch[23];enacheckinv=curcolsch[24];invcheckinv=curcolsch[25];prespritesheet=github+curcolsch[26];
   cwpp=curcolsch[27]}
```

```
var settings = pretaskbartxt,pretaskbartxtprs,preactivetitle,preinactivetitle,pretbgradinactive1,pretbgradinactive2,pretbgradactive1,pretbgradactive2,cpwhite,cplightg,cpsilver,cpmidgray,
   cpgray,cpblack,cpblue,cpprussian,cpwincyan,cpyellow,cpfont,cphover,cpatext,preinvert,shuffleflop,discheckinv,enacheckinv,invcheckinv,prespritesheet,cwpp,currentcolour
```

And just do a for loop?

```
for(var i=0; i<curcolsch.length; i++){settings[i]=curcolsch[i]}
```

The current result just ends up changing the value of that number in the array, and just changes it to the same thing as the current position in the curcolsch array. So my question is; how would I go about using a quicker route than just spamming the same set of variables with one step up in the array like I addressed above?

Just to be clear I'm not completely insane with the variable count problem, the whole reason i'm asking is so I can get rid of them.

Comment: That many standalone variables is a real code smell IMO, and it results in problems like these. If I were you, I'd omit them entirely and use just the `curcolsch` (probably turn it into an object instead of an array)

Comment: Just to be clear I'm not completely insane with the variable count problem, the whole reason i'm asking is so I can get rid of them and replacement with an array instead of relying on seperate vars.

Comment: Like I said, ditching the array and using a single object instead seems like it'd work.

Comment: it would if I knew anything about objects.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was hoping for a quick straight forward answer without the need to rewrite half my code, so I've just ended up removing all my variables in a replacement for a single array so I can switch easier and it's more compact + better than any other solution.

```
var preactive = [undefined,undefined,'--preactivetitle','--preinactivetitle',undefined,undefined,
   undefined,undefined,'--prewhite','--prelightg','--presilver','--premidgray','--preblack',
   '--preblue','--preprussian',undefined,'--preyellow','--prefont','--prehover',undefined,
   '--preinvert']
function themepreviewchange() { precolsch = undefined; precolsch = schemes[themecurrent]
   for(var i = 0; i<preactive.length; i++){docelem.style.setProperty(preactive[i], precolsch[i])}
   gradient = "linear-gradient(90deg, " + precolsch[4] + "," + precolsch[5] + ")";
```

Answer (score 0):

Hoping this isn't your homework assignment....

```
let settings = {
   pretaskbartxt: curcolsch[0],
   pretaskbartxtprs: curcolsch[1],
   ...
  cwpp: curcolsch[27],
};

for (const aThing in settings) {
   console.log(`value of ${aThing} is ${settings[aThing]}`);
}
```

Should give you the basic idea....